# Issue with SVG Circles - Trying to make a Speedometer

Tags: typescript, vue.js, math, svg

Im trying to create a speedo in a component of my vue project. But i've got an issue. If i pass 0 into my calculation progress to calculate the stroke fill in my project it "overlaps" the other circle, which should be the background circle. I guess my explanation isn't good enough. So here are Screenshots & Code.

[What it should look like if i pass 0 as fillLevel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uELus.png)

[What it actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO2Nl.png)

[What it looks like when its full filled - To understand what my problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlx4E.png)

So basically i dont want the orange circle to go over the grey circle which is in the 1st screen. The orange circle should have the same length when fillLevel is 0

This is my code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';

const fillLevel = ref(0); // max value = 360
const circleRef = ref<SVGCircleElement | null>(null);
const backgroundCircleRef = ref<SVGCircleElement | null>(null);

const circleLength = ref(0);
const strokeDashoffset = ref(0);

const calculate = () => {
  if (circleRef.value && backgroundCircleRef.value) {
    circleLength.value = backgroundCircleRef.value.getTotalLength() * 0.8;
    strokeDashoffset.value = circleLength.value * (1 - fillLevel.value / 360);
  }
}

onMounted(calculate);
watch(fillLevel, calculate);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="speedo-div">
    <svg style="width: 24vh; height: 23vh;" viewBox="0 0 271 265" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <!-- some overlay, you can see it in screenshots -->
    </svg>
    <div class="speedo">
      <svg class="speedo-svg" viewBox="0 0 240 230" transform="rotate(125.5)">
        <circle ref="backgroundCircleRef" class="circle" stroke="#53535399" r="35%" cy="50%" cx="50%" :stroke-dasharray="circleLength" />
        <circle ref="circleRef" class="circle active" stroke="var(--primary)" r="35%" cy="50%" cx="50%" :stroke-dashoffset="strokeDashoffset" :stroke-dasharray="circleLength" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.speedo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 24vh;
  height: 23vh;
  bottom: 0;
}

.speedo-svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 24vh;
  height: 23vh;
}

.speedo-svg .circle {
  stroke-width: 25px;
  opacity: .8;
  fill: none;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .2s linear;
}

.speedo-svg .circle.active {
  filter: drop-shadow(var(--primary-shadow));
}
</style>
```

Thanks for reading!

I hope someone can help me. This is my first time really working with SVG's. And also, please dont blame me about using vh on width. It's a stupid habit.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Did you see that this uses  [Vue script setup](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html)? I don't think your tips apply there. For example, non of the variables are global.

Comment: Fair, totally missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `stroke-dasharray` pattern does not repeat within the visible area. At the moment, the pattern is a dash of 80% of the total length, followed by a gap of the same length. When `fillLevel` is 0, the pattern is pushed by that length, meaning it starts right with the gap. And at 80% of the length, the gap is over and the next dash starts - which is the red bar you are seeing.

Since you want the whole circle to be empty, the gap should take up the whole length of the circle:

```
const calculate = () => {
  if (!backgroundCircleRef.value) {
    return
  }
  const fullCircleLength = backgroundCircleRef.value.getTotalLength()
  const dashLength = fullCircleLength * 0.8
  speedoLength.value = dashLength + ' ' + fullCircleLength // <---- gap is full circle

  strokeDashoffset.value = dashLength * (1 - fillLevel.value / 360)
}
```

Now, when you start at the end of the dash, the gap takes up the whole circle.

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)